# First item on my drop down IS HIGHLIGHTED

Tags: html, css, menu

This is my first attempt at a css dropdown menu. I have never done this before and have already come up with problems. The menu drops down fine and should be red in color. (which it is) but the first one takes the bg image isntead of the red bg the ones under it have. Please view this code in jsfiddle of something and tell me on how I would be able to fix it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css' />
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='team'><span>Team</span></a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href='team'>Team</a></li>
        <li><a href='team'>Team2</a></li>
        <li><a href='team'>Team3</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='sponsors'><span>Sponsors</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='first'><span>First</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='contact-us'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='handouts'><span>Handouts</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

AND THE CSS:

```
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: url(../images/bg.png) repeat-x top left;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
 #cssmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 #cssmenu li ul {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
}

 #cssmenu li ul li {
display: block;
}

 #cssmenu li:hover ul {
display: block;
 }
#cssmenu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #A79787;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 9px 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 }
#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu .active {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(../images/bg.png) repeat-x top left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu .active a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
 #cssmenu ul {
  background-color: #B11718;
}
#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu li.active {
  background-color: #DE3330;
}
```

HOPEFULLY YOU CAN ALL HELP ME OUT. Thanks.

Comment: `Please view this code in jsfiddle `? You ask a question, so you should **provide one**.

Comment: there you go buddies http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/aHYY2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Just1End/vAMTJ/  The problem is that the image wont show on it so its pointless.

Comment: Jonas. You added an image on hover for the top. I would like it static throughtout the entire menu.... with a lighter version on hover top. The dropdown should be normal red

Comment: it also..... shows the image on hover. Please help O.o

Answer (score 0):

Change background-color to background so it will override your previous style.

```
#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu li.active {
background: #DE3330;
}
```